# Adding text to a label from another class. Java

Tags: java, button, label

In my program, there are two `Form` and `Checked` classes.

In the `Form` class, there is a `Label` and a `Button`. At the click in the `Button` I create an instance of the class `Checked` and start its thread.

Now, what I'm having trouble with is that I need to pass the text from the `Checked` class and change the `Label` value, but I have not succeeded.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainForm extends Application {
    protected static int intVerifiedNews = 0;
    Button btnPlay = new Button("Button");
    Label lbVerifiedNews = new Label("News: ");
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        final BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
        final HBox hbox = addHBox();

        Scene scene = new Scene(border, 850, 500, Color.BLACK);

        btnPlay.setPrefSize(100, 24);
        btnPlay.setMinSize(24, 24);

        btnPlay.setOnAction((event) -> {
                    Checked ch = new Checked();
                    ch.start();
                }
        );

        border.setTop(hbox);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(btnPlay, lbVerifiedNews);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
    private HBox addHBox() {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 0, 5, 5));
        return hbox;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Checked class:

```
public class Checked extends Thread {


    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    MainForm.intVerifiedNews ++;
//Here you need to pass the intVerifiedNews value to the Label 
                System.out.println(MainForm.intVerifiedNews);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `lbVerifiedNews` into the constructor of the `Checked` class and store this reference in a field.

`Checked ch = new Checked(lbVerifiedNews);`

```
public class Checked extends Thread {

    Label checkedLabelReference;
    public Checked(Label label){
        this.checkedLabelReference = label;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            MainForm.intVerifiedNews ++;
            //Here you need to pass the intVerifiedNews value to the Label 
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    checkedLabelReference.setText(MainForm.intVerifiedNews);//update text
            }});
            System.out.println(MainForm.intVerifiedNews);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-7

Comment: Updated the code with `Platform.runLater(...)` hope this works. Cant test it by myself

Answer (score 0):

Generically you'll want to pass reference to the `MainForm` or form object that you want to update into your `Checked` class so that you have access to its update methods directly.

```
public class Checked implements Runnable {

   public Checked(MainForm form1) {
   // store form (or the object representing the text box directly) to update later
   }

   public void run() {
   }
}
```